# Creating a dashboard in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, dashboard

I am looking at creating a dashboard in Excel using several key performance indicators to plot a graph. The data would just be collected from another sheet in Excel. I understand that you can do this in conjunction with macros but my experience with macros is limited, although I am willing to learn.

Any help would be great!

Comment: This looks like a good link: http://www.excelcharts.com/blog/how-to-create-an-excel-dashboard/, found [here](http://www.google.com/search?q=dashboard+excel)

Answer (score 1):

You might start without macros and learn VBA only if you need a feature you really want. Some links may help you get started:

- [Excel charts](http://www.excelcharts.com/blog/how-to-create-an-excel-dashboard/), already mentioned by Benjol
- [Yet another math programming consultant](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2010/01/excel-dashboards.html)
- [Juice Analytics](http://www.juiceanalytics.com/writing/designing-great-dashboards-part-3)

Comment: Any step by step instructions? I'm still confused on how this will work

Comment: I guess for a step by step instruction you should elaborate more on what you want to achieve. What would be wrong with an array of diagrams?

Answer (score 0):

Darren,

Plotting a graph or any data for certain section (which is DASHBOARD for you) from an existing sheet in a single EXCEL WorkBook (File) is easy. You jut need to select graph wizard and point to the cell ranges in that sheet.

You can also plot this from another sheet as long as know the path. This can be controlled by writting some code to make it more dynamic.